# CSS styles aren't applying in my React app

Tags: css, reactjs

When I add new HTML code to my React app , the CSS styles from the App.css file aren't applying anymore , until I retype `Import './App.css'"` in the head.
Any solution please.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved , it was about bootstrap .

Import `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` before `App.css` .

I was doing the opposite .

Comment: Dear friend , You never mentioned you were using any third party CSS library in your Questions :) Anyways, happy coding friend. So, what was happening in your case was, App.css styles were getting override from classes in Bootstrap :) cool. As per your question asked @Rachid, I have answered it earlier. If it has helped you in any way or form, do please accept it as it takes encourages me to help more and more developers :) Thank You

Answer (score 1):

All our components in React act like modules and have their data (variables, functions) private to them. To access code or styles from other files we need import from other modules.

Our **App.js** is also one such component. Until you do `import './App.css'`, the CSS will not be applied to App.js.

Comment: So I just have to delete and retype ```import './App.css'``` everytime I edit the HTML code in App.js ? doesn't seem like a sweet solution

Comment: Why would you be deleting it? You leave the import statement in your top level file

Comment: thats the problem in the first place . I am leaving the import and the CSS won't applied until I retype it. @Grant

Comment: @RachidL'harime There could be a few reasons why that is happening, we would need to know more details about your individual case, i.e share some code with us, it could even be a build issue with your current tools but we won't be able to diagnose it any further without more information

Comment: @Rachid: Bro, There are few ways to include CSS in our React. 1 is keep everything in index.css file, second is using Same named CSS file as your component and then importing in that component. Which you are trying to do.

Comment: @Grant: If the project is created using npx create-react-app, there cannot be any build issue . By the way build has nothing to do with what is required. The only time changes may occur in our application is when we eject our project.

Comment: @RachidL'harime  What you are saying should not happen at any costs.I can give you a proof of why this should not happen. If you create a brand new project using npx create-react-app, as soon as the app starts, It has the css being applied from App.css. I feel you are making some other mistake while changing some stuffs.